# Expression for combining several probabilities in a single discriminator

Tags: experimental-physics, data-analysis

I'm doing an analysis of some experiment. Details are not very important, but I've stumbled on an expression that I cannot make sense of.

I have several simultaneous measurements of a certain parameter $x_i$. I also have precomputed pdfs, $\rho_i(x_i)$, for that parameter to be "bad". Based on these, I'm computing a confidence interval for each measurement:
$$P_i = \int_{|x_i|}^\infty \rho(x)dx$$

Then I'm told that I can combine these into a single discriminator using that expression:
$$P = Q \sum_i \frac{(-\ln Q)^{i-1}}{(i-1)!},\quad {\rm where}\quad Q=\prod_iP_i$$
I can understand the product of probabilities, but taking then that cryptic function from it, I'm not familiar with that at all.

I'm sure that this is something standard for the processing of experimental data. Can someone clarify what this means?